# Latest free-jqgrid, how to change font color on row being edited

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Currently using latest free-jqgrid with jqueryUI theme Dot-Luv for darker more contrast.

Rows that are not selected, selected but not in edit and hover have a text of white with dark blue or dark grey respectively.

When using inline editing (have not tried form editing yet), clicking the edit action button the row changes background to white and leaving the text also white. This makes viewing the current text and editing difficult.

Using the DOM explorer doesn't reveal any classes that are unique to the row being edited to allow a change of font color. Thinking if there was a method similiar to the onselectrow method or a class I am not seeing that I can manipulate the color. Otherwise maybe changing the theme using the themeroller, just not sure which part of the theme to change.

Any information would be appreciated. Didn't supply any code as the code operating as expected more of a style issue but can supply if needed.

Looking at the DOM and the CSS in the image it seems that maybe adding a class for all the input controls within the grid for the font color may work. Going to try but thought there might be a better solution.

[image: Image of CSS style by row type]

Comment: In all cases it is a good idea to provide a demo. In order to see from where come the problem I suggest you to remove all css files except the  needed for the grid and test - I men test with simple only grid files. If the problem does not appear it seems that some other css setting overwrite the ones from jqgrid

Answer (score 0):

What I eventually wound up doing was adding styles to the page's CSS stylesheet.

```
    #jqGrid > tbody > tr > td > input, #jqGrid > tbody > tr > td >  select {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
```

this is not optimal since there may be other editing controls that may need this style when in edit mode. And more importantly if using free-jqgrid on another page with a different table ID would have to duplicate this class everywhere the grid is used. Also makes it more difficult to change themes. Since the genius that down voted me because he could not come up with any real answer, it is what is going to be used.